# Winforms "Save" button (like we have in MS Word)

Tags: c#, winforms

My point is to create a save button like we have in Microsoft Word, for example. I know that there is already a post about "Save As" button but here is a difference. You click "Save" and if your file has not been saved earlier, you will get a window with possibility to set a name, directory etc. But if you have already saved the file, you will not get that window (unlike with "Save As"), changes will be saved for the file and this is exactly what I need

So I have this event, can somebody help me what's next?

```
private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
```

P.S. Already tried this:

```
private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Documents";      
            saveFileDialog1.Title = "Saving files";
            saveFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true;
            saveFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;
            saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "";
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*";
            saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
            saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.FileName.ToString());
                file.WriteLine(richTextBox1.Text);
                file.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What have you tried before asking your question?

Comment: How about a C# programming book for beginners? Start with the `if-else` block. Because instead of solving a specific problem, you're asking to write a program for you from scratch. That's not what SO is for.

Comment: @MortenToudahl yeah, I edited my question

Comment: You need a variable for the filename.  If it's empty, show the dialog, if not, skip the dialog and use the variable.  Side note: you are only saving the text part of the RichTextBox, not any "rich" text.

Comment: @LarsTech what do you mean by "use the variable"?

Comment: `string filename = string.Empty;`  and then later, `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename)) { \\ show dialog}`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you'd just need to track whether or not they've already saved the document, by capturing the file path in a variable. This way, if the value is not set you can show the dialog, and if it is set you just use the path to save the content.

You'd also want to update this variable in the `SaveAs` and `Open` events if you have them.

Here's an example:

```
// Stores the name and path of the current file
private string filePath = null;

// Enum to enable us to easily reuse the same method for getting a file path
// while still showing the appropriate dialog title (see 'UpdateFilePath')
private enum DialogType
{
    Open,
    Save,
    SaveAs
}

// Shows a dialog (based on 'dialogType') and captures the path in our variable
private bool UpdateFilePath(DialogType dialogType)
{
    FileDialog dialog;

    if (dialogType == DialogType.Open)
    {
        dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    }
    else
    {
        dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    }

    dialog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*";
    dialog.Title = dialogType == DialogType.SaveAs 
        ? "Save File As" 
        : dialogType + " File";

    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && dialog.FileName.Length > 0)
    {
        filePath = dialog.FileName;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var originalPath = filePath;

    if (UpdateFilePath(DialogType.Open))
    {
        try
        {
            richTextBox1.LoadFile(filePath);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to load specified file.");
            filePath = originalPath;
        }
    }
}

private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
    {
        if (UpdateFilePath(DialogType.Save))
        {
            richTextBox1.SaveFile(filePath);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        richTextBox1.SaveFile(filePath);
    }
}

private void saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (UpdateFilePath(DialogType.SaveAs))
    {
        richTextBox1.SaveFile(filePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry for another stupid question but what is "rtfMain"?

Comment: It was the name of the rich text box i had on my form. i updated it to match your name now.